# CRecordset::IsFieldNull method replacement in bulk row fetching

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, odbc

I have query related to bulk row fetching using `CRecordSet` (MFC ODBC).

On the MSDN page, it is written that

> The member functions IsDeleted, IsFieldDirty, IsFieldNull, IsFieldNullable, SetFieldDirty, and SetFieldNull cannot be used on recordsets that implement bulk row fetching. However, you can call GetRowStatus in place of IsDeleted, and GetODBCFieldInfo in place of IsFieldNullable.

Now, I want to check whether a field contains "NULL"/"has no value" data. How can I check this as the `IsFieldNull` function does not work in bulk row fetching?

Answer (score -1):

There is the difference between `IsFieldNull` and `IsFieldNullable` function.

So logically you will not be able to know whether a filed is null for a particular row since you are doing bulk row fetching. But you can only determine whether a particular field is nullable which simply means if that field is capable of accepting null values.

---

The `CODBCFieldInfo` structure contains information about the fields in an ODBC data source.

It has a member called `m_nNullability` which identifies Whether the field accepts a Null value. This can be one of two values: `SQL_NULLABLE` if the field accepts Null values, or `SQL_NO_NULLS` if the field does not accept Null values.

So pass the object of `CODBCFieldInfo` structure to `CRecordset::GetODBCFieldInfo` function which collects the object by reference. So no need to worry, you will get the updated value back and then check the member `m_nNullability` value of that object **to only know whether the filed is nullable and not whether a field for a particular row is null**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xexc6xef(v=vs.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k50dcc9s(v=vs.80).aspx

`CRecordset::GetODBCFieldInfo` function has two versions. One version of the function lets you look up a field by name. The other version lets you look up a field by index.